# $(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor \neg( p \to q ))$ Prove it using logical equilance. Please tell me if it is true???

Tags: logic

This is what i had tried
\begin{align}
&(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor \neg( p \to q ))\\
&\equiv(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor \neg( \neg p \lor q ))\\
&\equiv(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor ( p \land \neg q ))\\
&\equiv(p \land q) \lor ((\neg p \lor p) \land ( \neg p \lor \neg q ))\\
&\equiv(p \land q) \lor (\top \land ( \neg p \lor \neg q ))\\
&\equiv(p \land q) \lor ( \neg p \lor \neg q )\\
&\equiv\top\\
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What operator is "" supposed to represent? I'm assuming the conditional because it looks like you used a conditional exchange

Answer (score 3):

Everything is correct, but last step you still need a De Morgan's law:

\begin{align}
&(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor \neg( p \to q ))\\
&\equiv(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor \neg( \neg p \lor q ))\tag*{conditional equivalence}\\
&\equiv(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor ( p \land \neg q ))\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
&\equiv(p \land q) \lor ((\neg p \lor p) \land ( \neg p \lor \neg q ))\tag*{Distributive law}\\
&\equiv(p \land q) \lor (\top \land ( \neg p \lor \neg q ))\tag*{Negation law}\\
&\equiv(p \land q) \lor ( \neg p \lor \neg q )\tag*{Identity law}\\
&\boxed{\equiv(p \land q) \lor \neg(p \land q )}\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
&\equiv\top\tag*{Negation law}\\
\end{align}